# Can't get stream from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a very simple implementation of screen sharing using chrome extension. The problem is that when I try to test it using `serve` command, it works fine when I open `localhost:3000`. But if I try to host the web application from IIS on my PC and set a custom binding like: `mytest.com` it doesn't work anymore and the returned `streamId` from `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` method is null. Any idea what's causing this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you will need to add my test.com in manifest permissions. Plz chk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I had to use `HTTPS` URLs only. Chrome doesn't accept `HTTP` for security reason. So, I changed my local URL to `https://mytest.com` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [How to: Enable Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx).

And this [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc).

Comment: Your second link is linked to this page!